# How to convert geometry into Array Buffers in worker and pass it to main thread

Tags: javascript, three.js

Now, I want to use JSON data to create geometry in worker, and then return it to the main thread, but the geometry can not be transmitted directly. Is there any way to return the geometry to the main thread?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too braod to have a valuable feedback. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: can you construct your ArrayBuffer in the worker ?

Comment: My current approach is to generate geometries directly, not to construct arraybuffer. I just want to return geometries to the main thread. There is no limit to what to convert.